# Still can't understand why my TableView change listener does not work

Tags: java, javafx

I know my problem is trivilant and solution is on the surface, but I still can't deal with it and so need help. The problem is that TableView ListChangeListener in my code does not show updated changes. I have read many topics, manuals and examples before asked a question

[Javafx: Detect ALL changes made to tableView including addition/deletion of table rows and cell edits on any table rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050483/javafx-detect-all-changes-made-to-tableview-including-addition-deletion-of-tabl)

[Java ListChangeListener WasUpdated() doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29462624/java-listchangelistener-wasupdated-doesnt-work)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html#wasUpdated--

http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/2014/11/example-of-listchangelistener-for.html

but still can't understand why my code does not work. I have added `extractor` but it's not helped me.

Here is a part of my code

```
public class mainTableOverviewController {


    @FXML
    private TableView<EmailData> emailTableView;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<EmailData, String> emailNameColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<EmailData, String> emailLoginColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<EmailData, String> emailPasswordColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<EmailData, String> emailCommentsColumn;

    @FXML
    private Button handleDeletePerson;


    private MainApp mainApp;

    public mainTableOverviewController() {

    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        emailTableView.setEditable(true);
        emailTableView.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        emailTableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

        Callback<TableColumn<EmailData, String>, TableCell<EmailData, String>> cellFactory =
                new Callback<TableColumn<EmailData, String>, TableCell<EmailData, String>>() {
                    public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
                        return new EditingCell();
                    }
                };
        emailNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nameProperty());
        emailNameColumn.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
        emailNameColumn.setOnEditCommit(
                t -> t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow()).setName(t.getNewValue())
        );

        emailLoginColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().loginProperty());
        emailLoginColumn.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
        emailLoginColumn.setOnEditCommit(
                t -> t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow()).setLogin(t.getNewValue())
        );
        emailPasswordColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().passwordProperty());
        emailPasswordColumn.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
        emailPasswordColumn.setOnEditCommit(
                t -> t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow()).setPassword(t.getNewValue())
        );
        emailCommentsColumn.setPrefWidth(120);
        emailCommentsColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().commentsProperty());
        emailCommentsColumn.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
        emailCommentsColumn.setOnEditCommit(
                t -> t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow()).setComments(t.getNewValue())
        );

        emailData.addListener((Change<? extends EmailData> c) -> {
            while (c.next()) {
                if (c.wasAdded()) {
                    System.out.println("Added:");
                    c.getAddedSubList().forEach(System.out::println);
                    System.out.println();
                }
                if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                    System.out.println("Removed:");
                    c.getRemoved().forEach(System.out::println);
                    System.out.println();
                }
                if (c.wasUpdated()) {
                    System.out.println("Updated:");
                    emailData.subList(c.getFrom(), c.getTo()).forEach(System.out::println);
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        });

        emailTableView.getColumns().setAll(emailNameColumn, emailLoginColumn, emailPasswordColumn, emailCommentsColumn, actionCol);
    }
}

    @FXML
    private void handleDeletePerson() {
        int selectedIndex = emailTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        if (selectedIndex >= 0) {
            deletedDataList.add(emailTableView.getItems().get(selectedIndex));
            emailTableView.getItems().remove(selectedIndex);
            menuItemDisable.set(false);
        } else {
            nothingSelected();
        }
    }
    class EditingCell extends TableCell<EmailData, String> {
        TextField textField;

        EditingCell() {
        }

        @Override
        public void startEdit() {
            if (!isEmpty()) {
                super.startEdit();
                if (textField == null) {
                    createTextField();
                }

                setGraphic(textField);
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textField.requestFocus();
                        textField.selectAll();
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();
            setText((String) getItem());
            setGraphic(null);
        }


        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                if (isEditing()) {
                    if (textField != null) {
                        textField.setText(getString());
                    }
                    setGraphic(textField);
                    setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
                } else {
                    emailTableView.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(false);
                    emailTableView.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(true);
                    setText(getString());
                    setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
                }
            }
        }

        private void createTextField() {
            textField = new TextField(getString());
            textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap()
                    * 2);

            textField.focusedProperty().addListener(
                    new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                        @Override
                        public void changed(
                                ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0,
                                Boolean arg1, Boolean arg2) {
                            if (!arg2) {
                                commitEdit(textField.getText());
                            }
                        }
                    });

            textField.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
                    if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                        commitEdit(textField.getText());
                    } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                        cancelEdit();
                    } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB) {
                        commitEdit(textField.getText());
                        TableColumn nextColumn = getNextColumn(!t.isShiftDown());
                        if (nextColumn != null) {
                            getTableView().edit(getTableRow().getIndex(),
                                    nextColumn);
                        }

                    }
                }

            });
        }

        private String getString() {
            return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem();
        }

         private TableColumn<EmailData, ?> getNextColumn(boolean forward) {
            List<TableColumn<EmailData, ?>> columns = new ArrayList<>();
            for (TableColumn<EmailData, ?> column : getTableView().getColumns()) {
                columns.addAll(getLeaves(column));
            }
            // There is no other column that supports editing.
            if (columns.size() < 2) {
                return null;
            }
            int nextIndex = columns.indexOf(getTableColumn());
            if (forward) {
                nextIndex++;
                if (nextIndex > columns.size() - 1) {
                    nextIndex = 0;
                }
            } else {
                nextIndex--;
                if (nextIndex < 0) {
                    nextIndex = columns.size() - 1;
                }
            }
            return columns.get(nextIndex);
        }

        private List<TableColumn<EmailData, ?>> getLeaves(
                TableColumn<EmailData, ?> root) {
            List<TableColumn<EmailData, ?>> columns = new ArrayList<>();
            if (root.getColumns().isEmpty()) {
                if (root.isEditable()) {
                    columns.add(root);
                }
                return columns;
            } else {
                for (TableColumn<EmailData, ?> column : root.getColumns()) {
                    columns.addAll(getLeaves(column));
                }
                return columns;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the Class where list declaration are:

```
public class MainApp extends Application {
    public static ObservableList<EmailData> backupList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public static ObservableList<EmailData> emailData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(ed ->
            new Observable[]{
                    ed.nameProperty(),
                    ed.loginProperty(),
                    ed.passwordProperty(),
                    ed.commentsProperty()
            });

    private BorderPane rootLayout;

    public MainApp() {
        }
        public static void readCryptedData(String s) {
        try {
            switch (s) {
                    case "initData":
                    emailData = readDataFromStream(decryptFileBytes(libraryPath, salt, nonce));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        launch(args);

    }
               public static ObservableList<EmailData> getEmailData() {
        return emailData;
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        MainApp.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        MainApp.primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        MainApp.primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(imageFile.toURI().toString()));
        initRootLayout();
        try {
            showFirstView();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
           private void initRootLayout() {

        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
 loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("/fxml/RootLayout.fxml"));
            rootLayout = loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
            menuItemDisable.set(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
        return primaryStage;
    }



    @Override
    public void stop() {
        if (emailData.size() != 0) {
            saveDataToFile();
        }

    }

}
```

I will much appreciated for any help.

Comment: Update changes require the list to listen to changes of the property of it's elements. (see e.g. [`FXCollections.observableArrayList(Callback)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-javafx.util.Callback-)). You did post a lot of code (probably too much) but the declaration/initialisation of the list you seem to be asking about (`emailData`) is nowhere to be found. Furthermore the description of the issue is not really good. Why do you need this except for printing to the console? There probably is a better way of achieving this...

Comment: I don't wanted to attach another class where list declaration are. Now I updated my question and attached there class with `ObservableList`. I need to listen changes because I want to add the opertunity to restore changed data or deleted data.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. And though unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: I minimized the code in the question as I could. Because if I will delete much code it will looks like the code from other topics described on the top, but the problem is will remained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking for comments and minuses to my question, I saw that I need to search a problem in my code by myself. Hope somebody will find this question and answer usefull.
The problem was in my read method `readDataFromStream()`. Before reading topics mentioned above I  used such way declaration of `ObservableList`

```
public static ObservableList<EmailData> emailData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

And my `readDataFromStream` looked like:

```
public static ObservableList<EmailData> readDataFromStream(byte[] bytes) {
    ObservableList<EmailData> emailData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try {
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
        List<EmailData> list = (List<EmailData>) ois.readObject();
        emailData = FXCollections.observableList(list);
        bis.close();
        ois.close();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return emailData;
}
```

And then I have read that I need create the list with an extractor. And I changed `ObservableList` declaration to:

```
ObservableList<EmailData> emailData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(ed ->
        new Observable[]{
                ed.nameProperty(),
                ed.loginProperty(),
                ed.passwordProperty(),
                ed.commentsProperty()
        });
```

but my `readDataFromStream()` method remained the same. Now I changed it to:

```
public static ObservableList<EmailData> readDataFromStream(byte[] bytes) {
ObservableList<EmailData> emailData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(ed ->
        new Observable[]{
                ed.nameProperty(),
                ed.loginProperty(),
                ed.passwordProperty(),
                ed.commentsProperty()
        });
    try {
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
        List<EmailData> list = (List<EmailData>) ois.readObject();
            emailData = FXCollections.observableList(
        list,
        (EmailData tp) -> new Observable[]{tp.nameProperty(), tp.passwordProperty(),
                tp.loginProperty(), tp.commentsProperty()});
        bis.close();
        ois.close();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return emailData;
}
```

and `wasUpdated()` method of `ListChangeListener.Change`  now works like a charm.

Hope it will help newbies like me.